# Preferred use .on() method rather than .click(), .bind(), .hover(), .load(), .ready(), etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a better way to achieve the best performance and concise code use event delegation whenever possible.

Especially the correct **.ready()**:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

or

```
$(document).on('ready',function() //it is correct?
```

Other?

```
.click(), .bind(), .hover(), .load(), .ready(), etc.
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `$(document).ready` is always right for that particular event. If you need to reduce memory load then you can use `.on` on some parent element to capture events for the children.

Comment: As a sidenote, the documentation for [`ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) clearly states that one should **not** use `on('ready')` as it's not the same as `.ready()` -> *"There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0. "*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jQuery [.ready() docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the
>   DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $( handler )
> $( document ).ready( handler )
> $( "document" ).ready( handler )
> $( "img" ).ready( handler )
> $().ready( handler )
> ```
>
> As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other
>   syntaxes still work but are deprecated.

So the best and shortest way is this:

```
$(function() {
  // your code
});
```

For [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event and its friends it's more complicated.
`.click(function(){})` is a shortcut for `.on("click", function(){})` so they can be used interchangeably.

However [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function has additional feature for creating delegated events.

```
.on( "click", "selector", function() {});
```

So if you want concise code stick to the `.on()` version.