# Proper event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about proper event binding. I shoved my js code he said

> PROPER EVENT BINDING: Consider using the preferred .on() method rather
>   than .click(), .bind(), .hover(), etc.

```
$(".star").hover(
    function() {
      var prevStars = $(this).prevAll();
      prevStars.toggleClass('rate-btn-hover');
    }
  );
$("body").on("click", ".star", function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('rate-btn-active')
  var prevStars = $(this).prevAll().addBack();
  prevStars.addClass('rate-btn-active');
});
```

Can anyone tell me what that means ?

Comment: Refer to following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184794/preferred-use-on-method-rather-than-click-bind-hover-load-re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of the message is suggesting substituting

```
.on("mouseeneter", handleEvent)
```

for

```
.hover(handleEvent)
```

Comment: Yes you are right i found it but i don't understand why and how can i use it in my js code.

Comment: What is the source of the message? You can substitute `.on("mouseenter", function(){//do stuff})` for `.hover(function(){//do stuff})`

Comment: but if i use `.on("mouseenter", function({//do stuff});` then i get the hover problem. like this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/WobRYZ)

Comment: normalize hover working like this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/mOyRaE)

Comment: What is expected result at `mouseleave` event?

Comment: It should work like this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/mOyRaE). I mean when hovering first star then blue star will be come `.rate-btn-hover` if hover two star then first blue star still be stay and new blue star should be come. You can understand what it should work like `mouseleave`

Comment: i have tryed like this can you check it for me. Do you have better version ? [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/WobRYZ)

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean can you show me in my demo page please ?

Comment: i really don't understand how can i use this line exactly `$(".star").on({"mouseenter": handleMouseEnter})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127471/discussion-between-devstud-and-guest271314).